# How do I resolve these Node errors after running npm install in my project directory after installing Understrap for WordPress development?

Tags: node.js, wordpress, npm

I am trying to teach myself web development and so far it's making my head hurt, but I'm not giving up. At the moment, I am trying to learn WordPress theme development using the Understrap framework. This is what I have done so far to try and get it all working:

1. Install Node using Homebrew on my Mac
2. Created a project folder on my Desktop
3. Ran the following git command to install Understrap in my project folder: git clone https://github.com/understrap/understrap.git
4. Then ran npm install within the director in a terminal window

After doing all of this, I keep getting the following errors, but not being a seasoned web dev expert, this has me a bit boggled:

```
72 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

6 high severity vulnerabilities

To address issues that do not require attention, run:
  npm audit fix

To address all issues (including breaking changes), run:
  npm audit fix --force
```

Then I ran "npm audit" to get a better idea of the issue and this is where I am completely lost and hoping one of you fantastic folks on here can provide some assistance:

```
glob-parent  <5.1.2
Severity: high
Regular expression denial of service - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-ww39-953v-wcq6
fix available via `npm audit fix --force`
Will install gulp@3.9.1, which is a breaking change
node_modules/glob-stream/node_modules/glob-parent
node_modules/glob-watcher/node_modules/glob-parent
  chokidar  1.0.0-rc1 - 2.1.8
  Depends on vulnerable versions of glob-parent
  node_modules/glob-watcher/node_modules/chokidar
    glob-watcher  >=3.0.0
    Depends on vulnerable versions of chokidar
    node_modules/glob-watcher
      gulp  >=4.0.0
      Depends on vulnerable versions of glob-watcher
      node_modules/gulp
  glob-stream  5.3.0 - 6.1.0
  Depends on vulnerable versions of glob-parent
  node_modules/glob-stream
    vinyl-fs  >=2.4.2
    Depends on vulnerable versions of glob-stream
    node_modules/vinyl-fs

6 high severity vulnerabilities

To address issues that do not require attention, run:
  npm audit fix

To address all issues (including breaking changes), run:
  npm audit fix --force
```

BTW, I ran "npm audit fix --force", but it did not resolve this issue.

Thank you all so much for your help on this, I really appreciate it!